# Basic onClick not firing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

First time using NextJS, why is this not working. When clicking the button there is no log message in the browser. I have also tried adding onChange to an `<input />` however again, doesn't fire.

I have removed all styling from the globals.css and page.module.css file - this is literally a completely fresh NextJS project using `npx create-next-app@latest`

```
"use client";

export default function Home() {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log("hello");
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: make sure you saved the code changes.

Comment: @Yilmaz I have been saving + refreshing the page throughout trying different events, no luck there.

Comment: try on a different browser. sometimes plugins cause bugs

Comment: @Yilmaz Just tried on Edge which has no extensions added - same issue. I also just created the same project, but using Vite instead and everything works as expected. Very odd that no events seem to be working using NextJS

Comment: very interesting. if this is a test project, can you share the github

Comment: You should consider sharing your GitHub URL so that we can assist you better.

Comment: Hey, I tried starting the development server, and it works fine for me. I can easily trigger the onClick function in my Chrome. I don't know why you can't trigger this function. I think you should consider reloading by ctrl + shift + R. It will hard reset your Chrome.

Just one suggestion for you...
for ```app-index.js:31 Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded,data-gr-ext-installed``` warning:

Open your layout.tsx and ```suppressHydrationWarning={true}``` in your body tag.

Restart your development server too.

Comment: The URL of the image is https://mega.nz/file/FyI2xLQQ#wt7ABAYecHZ4hvFW_WGtiJFCKDBUPhS0wU2d6EeOCWY

Comment: @Tom what is your os?

Comment: @NirajKumarChaurasiya How strange... I tried hard refreshing and restarting my PC. No luck. I also don't receive this `app-index.js:31 Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded,data-gr-ext-installed` warning? My VSCode terminal is spammed with: `(node:10184) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)` though?

Comment: @Yilmaz Windows 10

Comment: I am on linux and cannot start the development server. it throws a weird error

Comment: Your code works perfectly with log printed on every click event, Check the sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-949sy4

Comment: @samnoon The sandbox works for me too - but still no luck on `npm run dev`. See this gif of me trying it on my dev server: https://gyazo.com/ce07e2463f239bc7825209f542397f97

Comment: I am also on Windows 10. I don't think it has to do anything with OS.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings?? If any, please let us know.

Comment: @NirajKumarChaurasiya See screenshot of my VSCode console. Not sure if this is normal for NextJS as this is my first time using it? https://gyazo.com/e90331a2ba5bcbc34c08876ffa0645e8 - no other errors apart from this

Comment: Nope, this is normal. Can you make another project using ```yarn create next-app client```
or ```npx create-next-app client``` 
and see if this issue persists?

Comment: @NirajKumarChaurasiya Sure - I did already create another project before posting but will try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255066/discussion-between-niraj-kumar-chaurasiya-and-tom).

Comment: I had some system issue. your code works. it logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused due to my Node.js being on v16.13.1. Updating to the latest version (currently v18.17.1) and also running `npm update npm -g` fixed the problem.